# Real life examples of Scala infix types

Tags: scala

I've found one interesting syntax stuff. It's called `Infix type`.

Example:

```
class M[T, U]
new (Int M String)
```

And now I'm looking for examples of this type from some popular frameworks or libraries. Where can I find them? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### [shapeless library](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)

has bunch of them

#### [Polymorphic functions](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values)

```
Set ~> Option
```

Much like

```
Set[A] => Option[A] forAny {type A}
```

#### [HLists](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists)

```
Int :: String :: Double :: HNil
```

is like a super-flexible version of

```
(Int, (String, (Double, ())))
```

#### [Coproducts](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#coproducts-and-discriminated-unions)

```
Int :+: String :+: Double :+: CNil
```

is like super-flexible version of

```
Either[Int, Either[String, Either[Double, Nothing]]]
```

#### [Type tags](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/typeoperators.scala)

```
Int @@ NonNegative
```

Is zero-cost runtime analog of `Int` with some information remembered in tag type

### [scalaz library](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz)

as Archeg mentioned has even more of them

#### [Either](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.1.4/scalaz_2.11-7.1.4-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.$bslash$div)

```
String \/ Long
```

Is cooler version of scala's `Either[String,Long]`, read more [here](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day7)

#### [These](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.1.4/scalaz_2.11-7.1.4-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.$bslash$amp$div)

```
Boolean \&/ Long
```

Is handy implementation of

```
Either[(Boolean, Long), Either[Boolean, Long]]
```

#### [Map](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.1.4/scalaz_2.11-7.1.4-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.$eq$eq$greater$greater)

```
String ==>> Double
```

is haskellest version of

```
collection.immutable.TreeMap[String, Double]
```

#### [Monoid Coproduct](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.1.4/scalaz_2.11-7.1.4-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.$colon$plus$colon)

```
String :+: Float
```

is alternated list of things, where similar things are aggregated (added, concatenated, choosed max, etc.) instead of sequencing

Comment: +1 not because of the infix ops list, but because of highlights of those libs I've never had time to wrap my head around. Makes stuff easier to understand.

Answer (score 5):

From scala language, generalized type constraints

```
=:=  =>  A=:=String => A must be String
<:<  =>  A<:<String => A must be subtype of String
```

Answer (score 4):

In scala library there is a class named `::`. It is used so you could match the list like this:

```
def m(l : List[Int]) = l match {
  case a :: b => println("Matched")        // The same as case ::(a, b) => ...
  case _ => println("Not matched")
}
```

There are lots of other examples in libraries like scalaz I think, but this one is the most canonical.

**Updated**

Just understood that it is not exactly what you wanted - you wanted types. Was adding `=:=` and `<:<` to the answer, but @johny was faster. Please see his answer