# Scala: shorthand for types parameterised with two types

Tags: scala

Scala allows using the following type:

```
=:=[Int, String]
```

as:

```
Int=:=String
```

This feature doesn't seem to be limited to this type and I can also have for example:

```
type Or[A,B] = Either[A,B]
val x: Int Or String = Right("value")
```

How is this working?

Comment: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#infix-types

Comment: And examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347955/real-life-examples-of-scala-infix-types

Comment: @Evgeny I have given some examples myself :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works [as described in the specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#infix-types). If this is too formal and too abstract, here is a short illustration of what it says.

1. You can use arbitrary identifiers for infix types, so all of the following definitions are valid:

   ```
   type foobar[X, Y] = (X, Y)
   type <=[X, Y] = Y => X
   type !+?[X, Y] = (X, Y)
   type `or failure`[X, Err] = scala.util.Either[Err, X]

   val x: Int foobar String = (42, "hello world")
   val y: String <= Int = n => "#" * n
   val z: Int !+? Float = (42, 3.1415f)
   val w: Int `or failure` String = scala.util.Right(42)
   ```
2. The arguments to the infix types are not restricted to kind `*`, it also works with higher-kinded parameters:

   ```
   type of[F[_], X] = F[X]
   val l1: List of Int = List(42)
   ```
3. There is no operator precedence. Infix types all associate either to left or to right:

   ```
   type +[A, B] = scala.util.Either[A, B]
   type *[A, B] = (A, B)

   // It's     ((Int * String) + Float) * Double
   // It's NOT (Int * String) + (Float * Double)
   val a: Int * String + Float * Double =
     (scala.util.Left((42, "foo")), 1.0d)
   ```
4. Infix types that end with `:` associate to the right:

   ```
   type -:[A, B] = B => A

   val f: String -: Int -: Double =
     (g: (Double => Int)) => "foo" * g(42d)

   // Not: (g: Double) => (i: Int) => "foo"
   ```
5. Left-associative and right-associative infix operators cannot be mixed:

   ```
   // error: left- and right-associative operators
   // with same precedence may not be mixed
   val wontCompile: Int * Int -: Int = i => (i, i)
   ```

Comment: @laughedelic Thanks, I probably should look up in the MD documentation how this list-code interaction works in the proper way...

Comment: It's a bit tricky here, because SO's markdown is not like on Github, for example. But a general rule is that any kind of nesting in lists is 4 spaces. And here +4 spaces for the code blocks.