# Scala List Case Pattern match Implementation Question:

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to understand the scala implementation of List pattern match and 
have question on how the first case statement(:: which splits the list by 1st, 2nd and rest) is implemented under the hood in List.scala

```
  list match{
    case h1 :: h2 :: rest => println(h2)
    case _ => 
  }
```

I was trying to understand by comparing this against Option Monad and below is my understanding on how Option case pattern match works:

When i wrap an object inside Option below is called from `Option.scala` and it gives me either Some or None

```
def apply[A](x: A): Option[A] = if (x == null) None else Some(x)
```

then When i pattern match on Option, one of the below is matched and I can call methods of the same

```
final case class Some[+A](x: A) extends Option[A] {
  def isEmpty = false
  def get = x
}
case object None extends Option[Nothing] {
  def isEmpty = true
  def get = throw new NoSuchElementException("None.get")
}
```

When i look for similar implementation in List.scala, i could find case implementation for Nil(`case object Nil extends List[Nothing]`) which will be called for `case Nil` pattern match
but i am trying to understand how the statement `case h1 :: h2 :: rest` is matched with List.scala case implementation

Thanks for taking a look and please add comment if my question is missing requirded information to look into it.

Comment: I really do not get your question, but trying to answer there is the [**case class** `::`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.8/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L448) which when pattern matched will return the `head` as the first result and then the tail as the second, and since the second is also a List, it can be pattern matched again, Thus `h1 :: h2 :: rest` says take the list and extract its head in `h1` and return the tail, which is again pattern matched to extract its head in `h2` and its tail in `rest`, basically it takes the two first elements of a List.

Comment: Scala pattern matching works using extractors. To learn more about extractors, you can refer to - https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html and https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/28/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-2-extracting-sequences.html and if you are curious only about this case then it works because of the `::` case class as pointed out by @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez when i write it as `case ::(h1,  (:: (h2, rest)   ) )`, i could kinda interpret it to be matching with `case class ::`..      Is `h1 :: h2 :: rest` a syntatic sugar for `case ::(h1,  (:: (h2, rest)   ) )` ??

Comment: @NareshKrishnamoorthy Yes, **Scala** has a notion called [_Infix Types_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347955/real-life-examples-of-scala-infix-types) which allows one to use and pattern match some classes like they were infix operators.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez that makes sense.. `h1 :: h2 :: rest` had always been looking magical to me and was curious how does that match to case class ::.. Now it makes sense.. Thanks for sharing link..